# How to use onclick function inside <a> tag which loads a script

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know much about coding but I wanted to use the onclick function inside  tag which loads a script from externally
like

```
 <div id="abc"><a onclick="https://abcd.com/script_include.php?id=226276"><div id="xyz"></div></a></div>
```

I used the above and I know it won't work 
what should I do to load the script

Comment: this is quite far away from anything that could reasonably work. Please explain what you are trying to achieve? why do you want to load that script? what with onclick? what is your real goal?

Answer (score 3):

the onclick-attribute must contain a JavaScript expression or a function call. A link to a script is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, use `href` instead because onclick requires javascript function.

```
<a href="https://abcd.com/script_include.php?id=226276"><div id="xyz"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is  a script to content locking . If I place it as a script in  it locks the whole page.
I want it too lock after a button has been clicked that button being "abc".
I guess only onclick function would work so I wanted an answer

Answer (score -1):

try using `href="your_link"` if you wish to navigate to the provided url

Comment: It would be good to expand on why you believe this to be a good solution for the OP.